# Moving cursor to input field after click button action

Tags: jquery

Am looking for a way that a customer on a site can be directed to a mandatory input field once a button is clicked.

Example is here http://www.hth.se/kop-online/varukorg/ if four products are added to a shopping cart (from köp online) the customer needs to click on Gå till kassan to proceed which should take them to http://www.hth.se/kop-online/kassa

but at the bottom of the form is a mandatory field Postnummer

Trying to see how we can move the input cursor to that field if empty

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] and take the [tour] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post code and effort

Comment: Have looked at a placeholder but it only seems to work with three or less products. The livechat js, when disabled, also has some partial success. But should be moving there all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".action-checkout").on("click",function(e) {
  var $postnummer = $("[name=shipping-postal-code]"), psval = $postnummer .val();
  if ($.trim(psval)=="") {
    e.preventDefault(); // cancel click
    // alert("Fyll i postnummer"); // optional
    $postnummer .focus(); 
  }
});
```

It needs to be in the load event. If you ajax in the link, you need to change to something like

```
$("#content-primary").on("click",".action-checkout",function(e) {
```

Comment: So that should go with the original code <div class="item">
    <div class="cart-buttons" id="cart-buttons">
        
        <a data-align="center" class="action-button  slim right-col  action-checkout" data-style="13" href="http://www.hth.se/kop-online/kassa/" data-overlay-style="">
            <span>Gå till kassan</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>